# image segmentation with the given coordinate data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a bunch of image data and the corresponding coordinate data which divided the images into several parts, lets assume there are A, B, C, and D parts, these parts of each image are in different positions. I try to build a model to train them, and then predict that the image will correctly correspond to each of these four parts. 
My idea is to make the image segmentation first and then do image classification.
So how do I make image segmentation with the given coordinate data, and what model and method should I use (if with PyTorch)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your corresponding coordinate data merely divide the image into parts? Or is it bounding box information? Do you have any labels for segmentation?

Answer (score 1):

I recently was working through the Deep learning with Python book by Francois Chollet.

Here is his notebook of applying image segmentation with tensorflow (sorry not Pytorch but concepts may be useful) on the Pet dataset.

https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter09_part01_image-segmentation.ipynb

To summarize - you'll need a folder containing your images, and a folder containing the image segmentation masks (also images). Each pixel on the mask could be either 0,1 or 2 for instance. So if you was to visualize it using matplotlib (when you multiply by 127, you have either black (0), 127 (gray) or 254 (near-white). Each pixel in your image should be a value between 0-1, you'll see in the neural network afterwards how we scaled this by dividing by 254.

The logic of your neural network is as follows:

- Conv2D operations are used to transform your data, finding useful features. The first few stacks will find basic things like vertical and horizontal edges. The deeper layers will then start to identify more meaningful representations, for example it could be an eye, face, ears.
- The transformations aren't predefined, these are actually unknowns (weights), that the model will figure out itself.
- Since there would be a large number of parameters we tend to downsample to prevent overfitting. In image classification we tend to use MaxPooling, but in image segmentation you want to use strides instead. This is because MaxPooling tends to destroy spatial information (you are taking a large grid of values and transforming it into one value, aggressively removing information. Strides are better for object detection/image segmentation tasks.)
- The output from these layers is representing large chunks of the image, with a reduced number of features (kind of like compression).
- However since we want to to predict a class for each pixel in image segmentation, we'll need to return to the original shape of the input image. So you'll have a new stack of convtranspose layers, which does the opposite to compression in order to return to the original image size.

I hope the above provided some basic theory.

At a high level you need to build a neural network that follows these general principles:

You'll have two key stacks of layers.

The first stack is as follows:

- Use conv2d layers with padding=same (and some of them to have a stide=2 to downsample)

This could look like the following:

```
def get_model(img_size, num_classes):
inputs = keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))
x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)

x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
```

The second stack of layers is an inverse of the above. Instead of 'compression', we are now trying to return to the original shape size of the image since in image classification, each pixel belongs to a class.

```
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same", strides=2)(x)
```

Finally you will apply a softmax function since you are classifying between multiple outputs as seen below:

```
outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", 
padding="same")(x)    
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
return model
```

Finally, if the performance isn't as expected, residual blocks and batch normalization are two key things that can help improve your model but I won't go into it in this post.

My best advice would be to work through an example online, or the one I provided above to help replicate it on some new data.